# Using pointer template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code:

```
struct Port {
    int reg1;
    int reg2;
};

#define PORT1 ((Port *) 0x00010000); // absolutely compile-time constants
#define PORT2 ((Port *) 0x00020000);

template <Port * port>
class PortWrapper {
public:
    PortWrapper() {
        port->reg1 = 1;
        port->reg2 = 2;
    }
};

constexpr static const Port * const port1c = PORT1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    PortWrapper<PORT1> port1; //Compiler says: error: could not convert template argument '65536u' to 'Port*'
    PortWrapper<port1c> port1; //Compiler says: error: 'port1c' is not a valid template argument because 'port1c' is a variable, not the address of a variable 
}
```

How can I instantiate this template?

I can do this:

```
Port port;
int main() {
    PortWrapper<&port> port1;
}
```

But that's not what I need. I need port to be mapped to predefined constant address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't as-is, because non-type template arguments of pointer type can only be null pointer expressions or addresses of objects, and a conversion from an integer is neither of those.

You could redesign the template slightly:

```
template <uintptr_t portAddr>
class PortWrapper {
private:
  static constexpr Port* port() { return (Port*)portAddr; }

public:
  PortWrapper() {
    port()->reg1 = 1;
    port()->reg2 = 2;
  }
};
```

Note that in the comments, @KonradRudolph disputes whether this strictly follows the rules for a `constexpr` function, and it's quite possible it does not. Nevertheless, even if `constexpr` is omitted from the above, any decent compiler will inline the call of `port()`, effectively resulting in compile-time evaluation.

Comment: Since when can a `reinterpret_cast` be a `constexpr`? Is this C++14? (I mean, sure, this will compile, but the result will *not* evaluate at compile time)

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're right, it needs a C-style cast. Amended. I'm stuck with VS2010, so I'm not up to full speed with `constexpr` rules. And I'd say that regardless of whether it fits the definition of `constexpr`, any decent compiler will evaluate that in compile time.

Comment: @Angew Actually as far as I know **no** cast is allowed here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph A C-style cast is not explicitly prohibited in a *core-constant-expression.* So it really depends on whether the result of the cast "evaluates to the address of an object with static storage duration." Probably not, but since "no diagnostic is required," it might Do The Right Thing anyway.

Comment: @Angew “no diagnostic required” never means “do the right thing”, it means that the compiler is allowed to let it fail silently.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Or it may silently keep translating it as a non-conforming program. So I still say it can work.

Comment: @Angew How is “non-conforming program” ever the same as a working program? It’s a broken program that accidentally *seems* like it’s working on one specific version of one specific compiler, on one specific machine, at one specific time. The next recompilation using the same configuration may break it. In addition I was apparently wrong, this shouldn’t even compile (although it does even with `-pedantic` on clang).

Comment: That C-style cast is a `reinterpret_cast`. The returned expression is not a core constant expression, and no set of arguments can possibly make it so because there's a `reinterpret_cast`. That makes the code ill-formed because `constexpr` functions are ill-formed if they cannot ever be constant. Any decent compiler will refuse to compile ill-formed programs. I don't understand what is there to weasel out.

Comment: If you still think you can weasel some interpretation that makes this code not ill-formed, note how C-style casts are defined as having "the same semantic restrictions and behaviors apply" as the conversion they can perform. That basically means that "You're right, it needs a C-style cast." makes no sense, because it changes *nothing* by definition.

Comment: @Angew: It won't. And even if it did the behaviour would be undefined and therefore worthless.

Comment: If you rely on the compiler inlining `port()` anyway, there's no point in making this a template -- just make it normal class.